# ImportError: dlopen failed: library "libavformat-4742719c.so.58.76.100" not found

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy

I am developing Tello Drone Application using Kivy module. I built the application using Buildozer module. When I try running the application from android mobile, I am getting the following error from the logs. Buildozer is using Kivy version 2.1.0.

This application uses Flask to get a video feed and pass it to the mobile application.

```
04-08 10:21:52.570  5491  5516 I python  : Initializing Python for Android
04-08 10:21:52.570  5491  5516 I python  : Setting additional env vars from p4a_env_vars.txt
04-08 10:21:52.570  5491  5516 I python  : Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
04-08 10:21:52.570  5491  5516 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app
04-08 10:21:52.577  5491  5516 I python  : Preparing to initialize python
04-08 10:21:52.577  5491  5516 I python  : _python_bundle dir exists
04-08 10:21:52.577  5491  5516 I python  : calculated paths to be...
04-08 10:21:52.577  5491  5516 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip:/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules
04-08 10:21:52.578  5491  5516 I python  : set wchar paths...
04-08 10:21:52.733  5491  5516 I python  : Initialized python
04-08 10:21:52.739  5491  5516 I python  : AND: Init threads
04-08 10:21:52.740  5491  5516 I python  : testing python print redirection
04-08 10:21:52.747  5491  5516 I python  : Android path ['.', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages']
04-08 10:21:52.748  5491  5516 I python  : os.environ is environ({'PATH': '/product/bin:/apex/com.android.runtime/bin:/apex/com.android.art/bin:/system_ext/bin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'ANDROID_STORAGE': '/storage', 'ANDROID_ART_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.art', 'ANDROID_I18N_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.i18n', 'ANDROID_TZDATA_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.tzdata', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/sdcard', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'DOWNLOAD_CACHE': '/data/cache', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/framework-graphics.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/apex/com.android.i18n/javalib/core-icu4j.jar:/apex/com.android.appsearch/javalib/framework-appsearch.jar:/apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar:/apex/com.android.ipsec/javalib/android.net.ipsec.ike.jar:/apex/com.android.media/javalib/updatable-media.jar:/apex/com.android.mediaprovider/javalib/framework-mediaprovider.jar:/apex/com.android.os.statsd/javalib/framework-statsd.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/framework-permission.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/framework-permission-s.jar:/apex/com.android.scheduling/javalib/framework-scheduling.jar:/apex/com.android.sdkext/javalib/framework-sdkextensions.jar:/apex/com.android.tethering/javalib/framework-connectivity.jar:/apex/com.android.tethering/javalib/framework-tethering.jar:/apex/com.android.wifi/javalib/framework-wifi.jar', 'DEX2OATBOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/framework-graphics.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/apex/com.android.i18n/javalib/core-icu4j.jar', 'SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar:/apex/com.android.appsearch/javalib/service-appsearch.jar:/apex/com.android.media/javalib/service-media-s.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/service-permission.jar', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote': '18', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_usap_pool_primary': '22', 'ANDROID_ENTRYPOINT': 'main.pyc', 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'ANDROID_APP_PATH': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'ANDROID_PRIVATE': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files', 'ANDROID_UNPACK': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'PYTHONHOME': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'PYTHONPATH': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app:/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib', 'PYTHONOPTIMIZE': '2', 'P4A_BOOTSTRAP': 'SDL2', 'PYTHON_NAME': 'python', 'P4A_IS_WINDOWED': 'True', 'P4A_ORIENTATION': 'landscape', 'P4A_NUMERIC_VERSION': 'None', 'P4A_MINSDK': '26', 'LC_CTYPE': 'C.UTF-8'})
04-08 10:21:52.749  5491  5516 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
04-08 10:21:52.750  5491  5516 I python  : AND: Ran string
04-08 10:21:52.751  5491  5516 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
04-08 10:21:52.807  5491  5516 I python  : Traceback (most recent call last):
04-08 10:21:52.808  5491  5516 I python  :   File "/home/sajith/Documents/drone_application/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
04-08 10:21:52.808  5491  5516 I python  :   File "/home/sajith/Documents/drone_application/.buildozer/android/platform/build-x86_64/build/python-installs/myapp/x86_64/av/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
04-08 10:21:52.809  5491  5516 I python  : ImportError: dlopen failed: library "libavformat-4742719c.so.58.76.100" not found: needed by /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/av/_core.so in namespace classloader-namespace
04-08 10:21:52.814  5491  5516 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

This is my buildozer specs file

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Drone Application

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,pyc

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, .buildozer

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3, numpy, Flask, djitellopy, opencv-python, plyer, numpy, kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
# icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/dove.jsp

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = landscape

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.1.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 26

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
android.minapi = 26

# (int) Android SDK version to use
android.sdk = 24

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 19c

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
android.gradle_dependencies = "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+","org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.0.0-nightly"

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
# android.ouya.category = APP

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
# android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/dove.jpg

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = x86_64

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
p4a.branch = develop

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Support me on this to overcome the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Buildozer does not use pip but, uses python-for-android(p4a) for installing packages. These p4a packages are called recipes.
This error occurs because there is no recipe for `av` module in p4a. You can check what are the available p4a recipes at [here](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/develop/pythonforandroid/recipes). You can build your own recipe using these [instructions](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/develop/doc/source/recipes.rst).